# How to unit test a WebBrowser attached property?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, tdd, rhino-mocks

I've created an attached property that works with a WPF WebBrowser. The WebBrowser class is sealed so I can't Mock it. The code is similar to this:

```
private static void BindableSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
    if (browser != null)
    {
        browser.NavigateToString(e.NewValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is there a way of testing this other that putting some logic on production code that allows the test to pass (like `WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser || sender as TestWebBrowser`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Rhino you can fake the method indirectly using a wrapper call to `WebBrowser` class.
For example:

```
private static void BindableSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender,
                                            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
    if (browser != null)
    {
        BindableSourcePropertyChanged(new MyWebBrowser(browser), e);
    }
}

private static void BindableSourcePropertyChanged(MyWebBrowser browser,
                                            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
        browser.NavigateToString(e.NewValue.ToString());
}
```

Where `MyWebBrowser` is a wrapper that forwards the calls to the real `WebBrowser`, since it's not sealed it can be faked. The original callback will not be tested but the logic there is almost meaningless since it just translates to an object to a wrapper.

If you're not bounded to Rhino, perhaps you can use an Isolation framework that supports sealed members fake. For example, using [Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/) it'll look like:

```
var browser = new WebBrowser();
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => browser.NavigateToString(null)).IgnoreCall();
```

There are other frameworks that support sealed members/classes faking other than Isolator.
*Disclaimer - I work at Typemock*

Comment: I'll use the wrapper call as we would like to continue with rhino, mostly because it's free and we are a large coding team.